# Get only one column from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to take a csv of three columns and n rows, and make just the elements of the first column into an iterable list. The problem I'm having is that it is taking a list that looks like this (in the code, "datalist"):

```
[
    ['56529.132', '16.9199', '0.152425'], ['56529.133', '16.4637', '0.127646'],
    ['56529.139', '16.4859', '0.12598'],  ['56529.139', '16.4011', '0.121806'],
    ['56529.147', '16.7835', '0.31821'],  ['56529.148', '16.3248', '0.179531'],
    ['56529.155', '16.3012', '0.146556'], ['56529.162', '16.1506', '0.174568'],
    ['56529.169', '16.1904', '0.180294'], ['56529.17', '16.0262', '0.164397'],
]
```

And isolating the first column into something that looks like:

```
56529.132
56529.133
56529.139
56529.139
56529.147
56529.148
56529.155
56529.162
56529.169
56529.17
```

In this second output, each individual character is an element of data all by itself, so that if I make it into a list like what I want, it looks like:

```
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['3']
['2']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['3']
['3']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['3']
['9']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['3']
['9']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['4']
['7']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['4']
['8']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['5']
['5']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['6']
['2']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['6']
['9']
['5']
['6']
['5']
['2']
['9']
['.']
['1']
['7']
```

How could I fix this? I need a list with each of these elements "intact," so it looks like

```
[['56529.132'],['56529.133'],['56529.139'],...
```

My code so far:

```
def read_csvfile(filename):
    import csv
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        datalist = list(reader)
    return datalist

in_confirm = read_csvfile('bin3test.csv')

def confirm_obs(in_confirm):

    for row in in_confirm:
        col1 = row[0]
        print(col1)


result = confirm_obs(in_confirm)
```

A bit of the data in the csv:

```
56529.132   16.9199 0.152425
56529.133   16.4637 0.127646
56529.139   16.4859 0.12598
56529.139   16.4011 0.121806
56529.147   16.7835 0.31821
56529.148   16.3248 0.179531
56529.155   16.3012 0.146556
56529.162   16.1506 0.174568
56529.169   16.1904 0.180294
56529.17    16.0262 0.164397
```

Comment: When you print(datalist) you get a list of lists as you show in the first printout? Then `[items[0] for items in datalist]` will return you the list of the first column items.

Comment: @dirkgroten so how would I make it clear that in datalist, for ['a','b','c'], a, b, and c are supposed to remain "intact?"

Comment: I don’t understand. In python a list is represented by comma-separated elements (in your case strings) inside square brackets. When you iterate over a list you get each element.

Comment: @GrantDonnelly Could you possibly post a line of two of your `'bin3test.csv'` file (keeping its format) so we can try to reproduce your results? thanks.

Comment: @davedwards yes I put some up in there now, thanks. That's a good idea

Comment: @GrantDonnelly you're using `delimiter = '\t'` when reading the csv file, but that's not consistent with the `csv` snippet you posted. Either double check the delimiter you specify, or maybe try using space (`' '`) as the delimiter. once the list is parsed correctly, then use list comprehension and slicing to get the first element as dirkgroten suggested.

Comment: try `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')`, and then after `in_confirm = read_csvfile( 'bin3test.csv' )`, put `col1 = [items[0] for items in in_confirm]; 

print col1` appears to work to get the first column. i get `['56529.132', '56529.133', '56529.139', '56529.139', '56529.147', '56529.148', '56529.155', '56529.162', '56529.169', '56529.17']` can you confirm this?

Comment: sorry formatted code in comments are not very readable. I can put this in an answer if you want to try it. Otherwise it appears the delimiter value is probably the main issue

Comment: correction to code in previous comment: `col1 = [[items[0]] for items in in_confirm]` should produce the sublists for each element like this result: `[['56529.132'], ['56529.133'], ... ['56529.169'], ['56529.17']]`, which appears to match your desired output.

Comment: @davedwards I just tried this, it does EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the first row like this:

```
first_col = [row[0] for row in in_confirm]
```

And then I'd get the individual characters/digits with either of these two methods (not sure which one you need):

```
[x for item in first_col for x in item]
# ['5', '6', '5', '2', '9', '.', '1', '3', '2', '5', ...

[[x] for item in first_col for x in item]
# [['5'], ['6'], ['5'], ['2'], ['9'], ['.'], ...
```

Comment: @GrantDonnelly Glad it helped! Is this the right answer then?

Comment: yes, I used the first_col line to get what I needed. Do I need to select a correct answer? If so, how?

Comment: @GrantDonnelly Yep. There's a grey check mark to the left of the answer, right under the vote widget. You click the check mark and it should turn green.

Answer (score 0):

Given in_confirm (also datalist):

```
first_values = [ [x[0].split()[0]] for x in in_confirm ]
```

If you don't need the data structure to be mutable, it's better practice to use a tuple:

```
first_values = [ (x[0].split()[0],) for x in in_confirm ]
```

but yes, it would be better to fix the delimiter problem on read.